# keyboard resigning reduces popover height

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a strange issue on ios 4.3.I have one of my screen in landscape mode, a button click presents  a popover.My popover has a search bar.Whenever keyboard appears it automatically pushes my popover bit up.When I resign the keyboard , popover reduces in height.This is the issue only on ios 4.3.While in rest of the ios , my popover doesnot reduces in height after keyboard dismissal.

Comment: I have the same issue with my app. I will post an answer as soon as I have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for this.It was a bug with the top arrow of popover.If I use the left arrow direction for popover, everything works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, and can verify that using any arrow direction does *not* solve the problem. :(

Comment: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft seems to solve the problem, if your popover doesn't overlap with keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above worked for me.  Apparently the keyboard scales the view and restores this scaling after the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification notification, making the presentPopoverFromRect method useless when applied handling this notification.
The way I solved it was by delaying the latter call as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    popup = nil;        //my ViewController with UITextField
    popover = nil;      //my UIPopoverController
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(resizePopup:)
               name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
             object:nil];
}

- (void)doDelayedResize
{
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:myButton.bounds inView:myButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:YES];
}

- (void)resizePopup:(NSNotification*)note
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(doDelayedResize) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01]; 
}
```

Comment: Your "delaying" tactic is the only thing that I've been able to get to work - the only negative is a little bounce in the animation - but better than nothing until Apple fixes... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I answered a very similar question here: [UIPopoverController's view controller gets resized after keyboard disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428425/uipopovercontrollers-view-controller-gets-resized-after-keyboard-disappears/5733411#5733411)

The way I got around it was to observe the keyboard disappearing in the controller which controls the UIPopoverController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(presentSearchPopover) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And then in `-presentSearchPopover`, present the UIPopoverController again (it's quite a seamless transition):

```
- (void)presentSearchPopover
{
    self.searchPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height));

    [self.searchPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:someRect) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer in `-dealloc` or similar too:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well - specifically, the popover wasn't growing back to its pre-keyboard size after tapping away from the popover.  (The popover would grow back if the user dismissed the keyboard directly or the popover's view controller resigned first responder).

Unfortunately, I have to use the top arrow direction for the popover due to the UI's layout.  To solve this, the view controller responsible for the popover implements `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`.  For example:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    // ...
}
//...
@end
```

Set that controller as the popover's delegate:

```
MyPopoverViewController *popoverVC = [[MyPopoverViewController alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverVC];
myPopover.delegate = self;
// Hang on to popoverVC, myPopover or release them as desired...
```

In addition, my popover's view controller sets its `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property to the desired size:

```
@implementation MyPopoverViewController
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // ...
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 400);  // desired size
    }
    return self;
}
```

When the keyboard causes the popover to shrink, it affects the popover's `popoverContentSize` and not its view controller's `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.  Therefore, reset `popoverContentSize` in MyController's delegate method:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    // Check if popoverController is valid, the popover you want, etc
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = popoverController.contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi After going through the forum, I don't think it's a bug after playing with frame sizes a lot, working on IOS 4,5,6,7 it's the same behaviour.

The solution for me was to:

1) Go into the designer by
2) Opening the XIB ViewController that is causing the problem (i.e. the PopOver one).
3) Click to select it's VIEW.
4) Uncheck "AutoResizeSubviews"
5) When loading the PopOver in code, make sure you do:
6) Your_Popup_Window.popoverContentSize = Your_ViewController.view.bounds.size;

I hope this helps.

Kind Regards
Heider Sati

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

**1.** Register for keyboard Notifications (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`)

**2.** Create local variables:

```
CGSize _currentPopoverContentSize; //if you want to have custom size for popover

UIView *_currentPopoverSender; //to remember from wich view you will present popover

BOOL _keyboardIsShown; //enable in keyboardWillShow, and disable in keyboardWillHide
```

**3.** In my presentPopover method:

```
- (void)presentPopoverControllerWithSize:(CGSize)size fromView:(UIView *)sender{

MyController *controller = [[[MyController alloc] init] autorelease];

if (self.popover)
{
    [_popover release];
    _popover = nil;
}

_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
_popover.popoverContentSize = size;
_popover.delegate = self;

//checking if keyboard is shown - if NO, than present popover, if YES - just `resignFirstResponder` for your _`activeTextField`(you can set it in -textFieldDidBeginEditing: and nullify in -textFieldDidEndEditing:)
if (!_keyboardIsShown)
{
    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                              inView:sender
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                            animated:YES];
}
else
{
    [_activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

_currentPopoverContentSize = size;
_currentPopoverSender = sender;
}
```

**4.** Than:

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     //do some stuff
                     [self.scrollView setContentSize:_scrollViewContentSize];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     if (_popover && _currentPopoverSender)
                     {
                         [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[_currentPopoverSender bounds]
                                                   inView:_currentPopoverSender
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                 animated:YES];
                     }

                 }];

_keyboardIsShown = NO;
}
```