# Positioning UIPopoverPresentationController when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

I am showing a UIPopoverPresentationController from a custom UITableViewCell. When the user taps on the cell we present a Popup that contains a UIScrollView with some editable fields.

[image]

The sourceView is set to the View of the parent Controller and the SourceRect is set to the TableCell

```
popoverPresentationController.SourceView = presentingViewController.View;
popoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any;

var rectInTableView = containingTableView.RectForRowAtIndexPath(path);
var rectInSuperView = containingTableView.ConvertRectToView(rectInTableView, containingTableView.Superview);

// The "/2" on the Height of the SourceRect was so the PopOver appear half way into the cell rather than at it's bottom edge
popoverPresentationController.SourceRect = new CGRect(rectInSuperView.X, rectInSuperView.Y, rectInSuperView.Width, rectInSuperView.Height / 2);
```

This works fine until the keyboard appears. If I do not listen to WillReposition delegate the popup animates away into the top left hand corner of the View

If I try and reposition the popup animates down to only 10 or so pixels high

[image]

1. Should I be managing the Popover from the outer view not the cell?
2. How should I be repositioning?

I have looked at [uipopover hides when keyboard shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827363/uipopover-hides-when-keyboard-shows) and [UIPopoverController's view controller gets resized after keyboard disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428425/uipopovercontrollers-view-controller-gets-resized-after-keyboard-disappears/5733411#5733411)